# MySQL case when involving week(), year(), curdate(), and weekday()

Tags: mysql

I have a data set with an order date and variations thereof (week(), year(), weekday(), etc.). I want to create logic that sums the units of the orders if and only if the order date meets certain criteria (e.g. week = 51, year = 2015).

Output I'm looking for:

product_id,
product_sku,
monday_units_sold,
tuesday_units_sold,
wednesday_units_sold,
thursday_units_sold,
friday_units_sold,
saturday_units_sold,
sunday_units_sold

The caveat here is that I only want units sold on those days if the order dates occurred within the last week. Also, I do not want this calculation to depend on any criteria in the where clause. I've shortened the request to keep it simple, but I will in fact be looking at different time frames in one select clause (life to date, mtd, ytd, etc.).

Here is the code I have thus far that will not work.

```
 select
    product_id,
    sku_code,
    case when week = current_week and year = current_year and weekday = 0 then sum(units_sold) end as monday_units,
    case when week = current_week and year = current_year and weekday = 1 then sum(units_sold) end as tuesday_units,
    case when week = current_week and year = current_year and weekday = 2 then sum(units_sold) end as wednesday_units,
    case when week = current_week and year = current_year and weekday = 3 then sum(units_sold) end as thursday_units,
    case when week = current_week and year = current_year and weekday = 4 then sum(units_sold) end as friday_units,
    case when week = current_week and year = current_year and weekday = 5 then sum(units_sold) end as saturday_units,
    case when week = current_week and year = current_year and weekday = 6 then sum(units_sold) end as sunday_units

from
    -- This table is at the order level whereas the final result rolls up into the product/sku level.
    (select
        order_date,
        order_id,
        product_id,
        sku_code,
        weekday(order_date) as weekday,
        week(order_date) as week,
        month(order_date) as month,
        year(order_date) as year,
        yearmonth(order_date) as yearmonth,
        units_sold,
        product_sales,
        -- I tried calculating this in each case when in the select statement above, 
        -- but moved it down here in an attempt to problem solve why my calculations aren't working.
        week((curdate() - interval 1 day)) as current_week, 
        year((curdate() - interval 1 day)) as current_year,
    from product_sales
    ) a
```

Comment: Aren't you missing something like `GROUP BY sku_code, weekday` in the outer query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your query:

```
select product_id, sku_code
     , year(order_date) as order_year
     , weekofyear(order_date) as order_week
     , sum(case weekday(order_date) when 0 then units_sold else 0 end) as monday_units
     , sum(case weekday(order_date) when 1 then units_sold else 0 end) as tuesday_units
     , sum(case weekday(order_date) when 2 then units_sold else 0 end) as wednesday_units
     , sum(case weekday(order_date) when 3 then units_sold else 0 end) as thursday_units
     , sum(case weekday(order_date) when 4 then units_sold else 0 end) as friday_units
     , sum(case weekday(order_date) when 5 then units_sold else 0 end) as saturday_units
     , sum(case weekday(order_date) when 6 then units_sold else 0 end) as sunday_units
from
    (
        select
            order_date,
            order_id,
            product_id,
            sku_code,
            units_sold,
            product_sales
        from product_sales
    ) as a
 -- Example of WHERE condition:
where year(order_date) = 2015 and weekofyear(order_date) = 51
group by product_id, sku_code, order_year, order_week;
```

Since the table can be quite big, maybe the best approach would be to create a temporary table, index it, and then select from that temp table. Something like this:

```
-- If the temp table exists, drop it
drop table if exists temp_product_sales;
-- Create a temporary table with the data you're interested.
-- I suggest you add the WHERE conditions in this SELECT, because it may
-- speed up the final SELECT.
-- Notice that I'm not grouping the data just yet... that will be done 
-- with the final SELECT
create temporary table temp_product_sales
        select
            order_date,
            order_id,
            product_id,
            sku_code,
            units_sold,
            product_sales,
            year(order_date) as order_year,
            weekofyear(order_date) as order_week,
            weekday(order_date) as order_weekday
        from product_sales
        -- Optional: Add WHERE conditions here
        ;
-- IMPORTANT: Add the relevant indexes to your temp table. This will
-- speed up things
alter table temp_product_sales
    add index odt(order_date),
    add index oid(order_id),
    add index pid(product_id),
    add index sku(sku_code),
    add index oy(order_year),
    add index ow(order_week),
    add index owd(order_weekday);
-- Finally, execute your final query:
select product_id, sku_code, order_year, order_week
     , sum(case order_weekday when 0 then units_sold else 0 end) as monday_units
     , sum(case order_weekday when 1 then units_sold else 0 end) as tuesday_units
     , sum(case order_weekday when 2 then units_sold else 0 end) as wednesday_units
     , sum(case order_weekday when 3 then units_sold else 0 end) as thursday_units
     , sum(case order_weekday when 4 then units_sold else 0 end) as friday_units
     , sum(case order_weekday when 5 then units_sold else 0 end) as saturday_units
     , sum(case order_weekday when 6 then units_sold else 0 end) as sunday_units
from temp_product_sales
-- Example of WHERE condition:
where order_year = 2015 and order_week = 51
group by product_id, sku_code, order_year, order_week;
```

Remember: Temporary tables are only visible to the connection that creates them, and are dropped once the connection is closed or killed.

Hope this helps

Comment: This does help. I've never used temporary tables and will give it a shot. The reason I can't use your first solution (putting the week and year of interest in the where clause) is because there are actually a lot more calculations of this nature I wish to do at the same time (week to date, month to date, year to date, lifetime) and I intend for them all to spit out on one row. I'll try the sum(case when). I had not thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: @jmo Happy to help! By the way, if you find this answer useful, please up-vote it (and if it solves your problem, consider accepting it ;) )

Comment: I figured out what was preventing my code to work because of your code (even though I couldn't use the overall set with the where clause). Sum() needs to go OUTSIDE of the case when. Oops. Thank you and yes, I'll upvote your response.

Comment: @jmo excellent! I'm glad you figured out your solution. If you find that your query is slow, consider a "divided and conquer" strategy using temporary tables for the intermediate steps